# If $R$ is a nilpotent ring. Prove that if $N\not=0$ then $RN\not=N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working on the following problem.

Let $R$ be a nilpotent ring (there exists a positive integer $n$ such that the product of $m$ elements of $R$ is $0$). Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ any submodule of $M$. Prove that if $N\not=0$, then $RN\not=N$.

What I have tried: 
I wanted to prove this by contrapositive. Assume that $RN=N$. We want to show that $N=0$. Let $a\in N$. Then $a\in RN$ and so $a=r_1n_1+\cdots+r_tn_t$ for some $r_i\in R$ and $n_i\in N$.

I know I should probably use that $R$ is nilpotent somewhere, but I am stuck on how to proceed to show that $a=0$. Any clues on how to proceed, or should I try a different approach?

Comment: A commutative ring?

Comment: The problem does not state that $R$ is commutative.

Comment: And $N$ is not finitely generated or anything?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the problem correctly. but it seems to me you could now replace each $n_i$, by such a sum. If you then expand the product, you'd have elements of $N$ preceded by a product of $2$ elements of $R$. Continue like this to have a product of $m$ elements, which is then $0$.

Comment: Yes, that absolutely works.

Comment: I was thinking this looked a lot like an application of Nakayama's lemma, but maybe the nilpotency assumption makes things a lot easier.